# How I save the file on server in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have send the file(Ex: A image) using Form data in JS and data received in Laravel backend side.

```
Array
(
    [filename] => imageedit_1_7173872236.png
    [filetype] => image/png
    [value] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjgAAAJFCAYAAADQyY3pAACAAElEQVR42uz9e
)

$emailFile = $userData['avatar']['filename'] ?? '';
```

After that I have set the path to save the file but couldn't save it.

Controller code:-

```
public function saveFile(Request $request){
    $userData = null;
    $user = null;
    $userData = $request->input();
    $user['file'] = $userData['avatar']['filename'];
    $user['value'] = $userData['avatar']['filename'];
    if(!empty($user['file'])){
        file_put_contents($user['file'], public_path('voiceRecording'));
    }
}
```

HMTL file:-

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Bob" formControlName="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
                  <input type="file" id="avatar" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" (click)="clearFile()">clear file</button>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid || loading" class="btn btn-success">Submit <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw" *ngIf="loading"></i></button>
              </form>
```

Component file:-

```
createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      avatar: null
    });
  }
 onFileChange(event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.get('avatar').setValue({
          filename: file.name,
          filetype: file.type,
          value: reader.result.split(',')[1]
        });
      };
    }
  }
 onSubmit() {
        const formModel = this.form.value;
        // API call
     }
```

Please help me?

Comment: What do you mean couldn't save it? What error are you getting?

Comment: $emailFile is string based on `$emailFile = $userData['avatar']['filename'] ?? '';` so you cannot call method move on it.

Comment: @Metalik Thanks, I have tried to put this function: file_put_contents($emailFile, public_path('voiceRecording')); and set the permission but getting "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error.

Comment: `file_put_contents($emailFile, public_path('voiceRecording'));
 base64_decode($'value);`

Comment: Thats more a right access issue that a bug. On which system are you working on ?

Comment: Hi I have fixed the permission issue able to create on server.

Answer (score 1):

`$emailFile` is string based on `$emailFile = $userData['avatar']['filename'] ?? '';` so you cannot call method move on it.

```
public function saveFile(Request $request) { 
    $user = null;
    $userData = $request->input();
    $user['file'] = $userData['avatar']['filename'];
    $user['value'] = $userData['avatar']['value'];
    file_put_contents( public_path('voiceRecording/'.$user['file']), base64_decode($user['value']));  
}
```

Comment: I am not sending any file.

Comment: Nothing is showing error. When I am trying to dump the array. it is showing 
`Array
(
    [filename] => imageedit_1_7173872236.png
    [filetype] => image/png
    [value] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjgAAAJFCAYAAADQyY3pAACAAElEQVR42uz9e
)
`
But If I am trying to print `$request->file('avatar')` nothing is showing.

Comment: please edit your question and put all of controller codes that related to upload process.

Comment: maybe you forget add `Request $request` to your controller method parameter.

Comment: This is my code:-  
  `public function saveFile(Request $request){
        $userData = null;
        $user = null;
        $userData = $request->input();
        $user['file'] = $userData['avatar']['filename'];
        $user['value'] = $userData['avatar']['filename'];
        if(!empty($user['file'])){
            file_put_contents($user['file'], public_path('voiceRecording'));
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the code which you given is not working. I have added the HTML and component file to send the data to server. Please check it once.